# cross table with percentages and significant differences

Tags: r, ggplot2, expss

I am trying to replicate this table in R, I did the above in Power Bi

[image]

try the following code because I have no idea where to start I have done everything but nothing works

```
library(expss)
as.datatable_widget(base %>%
                      group_by(CP1_TOTV2) %>%
                      summarize(weight = sum(weight)) %>%
                      tab_cells(weight / sum(weight)) %>%
                      tab_cols(total(), BANNER3) %>%
                      tab_stat_tpct(total_row_position = "above", total_label = "Total") %>% # aquí señalo los porcentajes total muestra
                      tab_pivot())
```

What I hope at the beginning is to form the same table and be able to add at the end a column that shows the significant differences between wave 2 and wave 3 per row, but I have not had any idea how to do it, I leave the data if you need to see how it is distributed [Data in sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uFSuzy65FBmDOGKQS4xqRH-YeVYwGaJo/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105825023377044710547&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: The data you have provided is not very easy to navigate making it hard to comprehend. I suggest you either provide a cleaner version of the data or you provide the simplified `tibble` or `dataframe` used on your analysis in `R`.

Comment: Do you have any example of how to summarize this type of data? The issue is that the "CP1_TOTV2" variable is split into 14 different parts, and in the cells, the words "yes" or "no" appear, with "yes" being the valid category. That's why I haven't been able to apply any analysis. In Power BI, what I usually do is pivot these data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna look at [data wrangling cheatsheet.](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) To get the basics.

It's hard to match the picture exactly since I don't know where the variables exactly are. But going by your comment, OP @yefersonG, here is an example of summarizing `CP1_TOTV2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df=read_csv("df.csv")

df=df%>%select(starts_with("CP1_TOTV"))


df |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = "CP1_TOTV")|>
  group_by(CP1_TOTV)|>
  summarise(Freq=sum(value=="Yes"))|>
  mutate(Percentage=Freq/sum(Freq),
         Percentage=scales::percent(Percentage))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, following I made the table adding the necessary variables  `df=base%>%select(starts_with("CP1_TOTV"),weight,BANNER3)`                 Then I made the percentage, I must calculate it with the 'weight' column.  `df |> pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = "CP1_TOTV")|>group_by(CP1_TOTV)|>summarise(weight = sum(weight))|>mutate(Porcentaje = weight / sum(weight),Percentage=scales::percent(Percentage))`  
My dear @derf  I hope this makes the problem I'm having easier.